# Converting this bufferedreader to string

Tags: java

I am trying to convert this buffered reader to a string but for some reasong the if statement will not recognize the first letter as a string

```
BufferedReader userInputMessage = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
message = userInputMessage.readLine();

firstLetter = message.substring(0,1);

System.out.println("FirstLetter: " + firstLetter + "/");
message = message.substring(1);
System.out.println("Message: " + message + "/");

if(!firstLetter.equals("0") || !firstLetter.equals("1")){
    System.out.println("First letter not valid!");
}
```

Comment: re `"Converting this bufferedreader to string"` -- A BufferedReader is not a String, nor can it be "converted" into a String.

Comment: How did you declare `firstLetter`?

Comment: Also, if your code is causing an error, please print the complete error message, and also indicate which line is causing the error to occur.

Comment: declared firstLetter as a string

Comment: Does it equal 0 or 1?

Comment: show us what error you get

Comment: It prints out "First letter not valid!" no matter what

Comment: Is there a way to convert a bufferedreader to a string so i can check if it equals something?

Comment: @RichardBarley thats the correct behavior .. your if statement is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will always be true:

```
if(!firstLetter.equals("0") || !firstLetter.equals("1")){
```

think about it. If first letter is 0, then the second part is true, if it's 1, the first part will be true, if it's anything else, both will be true. You want to use && perhaps:

```
if(!firstLetter.equals("0") && !firstLetter.equals("1")){
```

Comment: Simple but sometimes difficult to spot. Good catch! + 1

Comment: Thanks! it is sometimes difficult to spot

Comment: `!case1 || !case2` should as pattern immediately ring an alarm.

Comment: @JoopEggen: yep. A simple mental Venn diagram will show a big problem if case1 and case2 have an empty union set.